# SwiftUI sheet won't dismiss on Apple silicon Macs (works on iPhone)

Tags: ios, macos, swiftui, apple-m1

I have an iPhone app that is available on Apple silicon Macs, but I found a bug where the **`sheet` will not dismiss when the app runs on Mac**.

The app runs just fine on iPhone with the sheet dismissing properly.

The code is:

```
VStack {
  Button(action: { self.showingC.toggle() }) {
    HStack(spacing: 10) { Image(systemName: "eyedropper") }
  }
}.sheet(isPresented: $showingC) { CView() }
```

But the app running on Mac the `sheet` doesn't dismiss when swiped.

What would I need to do? I'm not sure what the paradigm on Mac is for this?

Comment: You might need to pass showingC to CView and add a button that sets it back to false. Basically add a close button.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez do you know why that works different on Mac vs iPhone by chance? Or do you have any developer documentation I might have missed from Apple that shows that? Thanks!

Comment: On macos, it's @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss